# Using diff command to find difference between two directories

Tags: linux

I wanna get changed parts in .diff files between the modifiied and the original kernel files. 
I use diff -b -r -w dir1 dir2
it gives it on command line but I wanna get it in seperate diff extension files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

diff -b -r -w dir1 dir2  >> your_file_name.patch

will save your result.

Comment: use a single `>` if you want to overwrite that file rather than appending to it.

Comment: +1 for this, -w ignores all white space & I think -b is not needed. And `diff -rw src_dir dst_dir` does the trick. Thanks!